# Motion of a sphere at the end of a structure

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, rotational-dynamics

I need help understanding the motion of the sphere given in the figure below...
The centre of this sphere lies at some horizontal distance from the vertical line ( If it is extended )

Will it have a horizontal velocity as well?

Thank you[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering the kinematics of the situation, there are two cases possible:

[image: fig1]

In the no-slip case, the velocity of the center is $v_C = \omega \, r$ and the contact point has no motion. The direction of velocity is perpendicular to the line connecting the corner (point **A**) and the center (point **C**).

In the slip case, the velocity of the center has the same direction as above, but differs in magnitude because the center of rotation is not on the corner, but at some other point along the line **AC**. The details depend on the specifics of the situation.

For both cases, **yes** there would be a horizontal component of the velocity, but it is undetermined in magnitude at this point.

Comment: Where is the sphere gaining it's initial velocity i.e. vsubc from?

Comment: I am discribing the kinematics of the situation (all possible motions), and I have no input as to what is the magnitude of the velocity. Just that if there is a velocity, it will be pointing in the direction shown and _yes_ it will have a horizontal component.

Comment: Assuming that the center of the cylinder's front face does not lie on the vertical line in the figure rather it lies at a horizontal distance from the extended vertical line, then won't there be any motion?...

Comment: Consider the body in the figure to be a cylinder...

Comment: @LuciferP the title states this is a sphere. In any case, with a cylinder the kinematics are the same, as the distance $r = \| \bf{AC} \|$ is preserved always.

Comment: What if more than half of the body doesn't lie on the horizontal surface?

Comment: @LuciferP - Dynamics is analyzed using one timeframe at a time, and in the instant shown in the figure it is not specified what the motion is. Unless you are asking about the acceleration of the object's center. The acceleration can be calculated from the geometry given, and the initial conditions (position, velocity).

Comment: @LuciferP - as long is the center is constrained to be a distance $r$ apart from the edge, the figures above are valid. It does not matter if the contact is a single point like the case of a sphere, or a line like the case with a cylinder, or whatever other shape.

Comment: If we consider half of the body's mass to be lying outside the horizontal surface initially...then how can we describe it's motion?

Comment: For example if we keep a tennis ball on a table with majority of it's mass lying outside the table then it'll fall down...How can we describe it's motion?

Comment: As I said above, the direction of velocity vector of the center is going to be perpendicular to the line **AC** at all times. Otherwise the ball would move inside the table. As for the magnitude of the velocity it depends on the specifics, and the initial conditions. I think I have answered your question thoroughly at this point since I keep repeating my self. Please award the answer that has helped you the most.

Answer (score 0):

The image shows only the initial position. The initial velocity is not shown in the picture and cannot be inferred from it. With the known laws of physics and both the initial position and initial velocity we can calculate how the position and velocity will change over time. But we must be given that initial velocity as a separate input.

So the short answer is we cannot tell if it has an initial horizontal velocity or not from the given information.

Comment: I've modified the question...

Comment: Please don't do that. Once you have received valid answers to a question it is against the site policy to make modifications to the question in a way that invalidates the answers already received. I have reverted the question back to the original. Please ask a new one instead.

Comment: Should I open a new query?

Comment: Yes, you should always open a new query in this case rather than invalidate previously received answers. It is also important to take the time to ask a good question the first time to avoid exactly this circumstance.